# How to understand the structure of "To the rescue has come the European Union"?

Tags: grammar

It comes from the newest edition of The Economist. The full sentence is

> **To the rescue has come the European Union**, which has devised a new labelling system, or taxonomy, that sorts the economy into activities it deems environmentally sustainable, from the installation of heat pumps to the anaerobic digestion of sewage sludge.

Is it some sort of inverted order? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In English it is perfectly normal for sentences to be structured both with the subject at the front, followed by the predicate and vice-versa - eg:

***Fred went to London*** means the same thing as ***To London went Fred***.

The difference is only in the type of stress that each example gives.

So ***To the rescue has come the European Union*** means essentially ***The European Union has come to the rescue***. But the person writing the article in question perhaps wanted to stress the idea of 'to the rescue' above 'the European Union'. This is everyday idiomatic English and perfectly grammatical.

Comment: I'm not sure that I agree that it's an everyday usage—it is a bit eye-catching. But I agree that it was probably done to move "rescue" in front of the EU in the flow of thought. I'm guessing the previous sentence was about a problem, and the writer wants to start this sentence by announcing that there is a solution, before disclosing who's providing it.

Comment: @AndyBonner Think of expressions such as 'Off went the train...', 'Up went the balloon...', '"Aha" thought I...', '"What?", asked the policeman' They all seem perfectly 'everyday' to me.